# Reducing or maping a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x

I need to reduce a list of tuples to a list of integers, by keeping the tuple element that is not present in the next tuple

```
import itertools
lis = [(31, 61), (61, 79), (29, 79), (29, 103)]
print(list(itertools.accumulate(lis, lambda a,b : a[0] if a[1] in b else a[1])))
```

So I would expect to get `[31, 61, 79, 29, 103]`, but I'm stuck with this exception
What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do this?

```
  line 3, in <lambda>  
    print(list(itertools.accumulate(lis, lambda a,b : a[0] if a[1] in b else a[1]))) 
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: This has the same API as JavaScript reduce, it doesn't make sense to treat the accumulator as a tuple when you're returning an integer from the callback.

Comment: so `a` is the acummulator? then I just need to compare his last value against `b`, right?

Comment: I'd recommend printing out the arguments to explore this behaviour.

Comment: Your task is suitable neither for map (works on only one element) nor reduce (output must have same type as the two inputs). Why di you want to use these anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the `OrderedDict`, because order of appearance is not important to you, use `set()` instead of `OrderedDict.from()` keys, and remove the second import statement.

```
import itertools
from collections import OrderedDict

# List of tuple initialization 
lis = [(31, 61), (61, 79), (29, 79), (29, 103)]

# Using itertools as requested.
unique = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lis)))

print(unique)
```

When run this outputs:

```
[31, 61, 79, 29, 103]
```

Comment: The OP wants to preserve the item not in the adjacent tuple only, rather than any of the previous tuples. This solution will result in lost items if the latter tuples contain items that are present in any of the previous tuples.

Comment: It does. Try `[(31, 61), (61, 79), (79, 31)]`. The expected result should be `[31, 61, 79, 31]` but your solution would result in `[31, 61, 79]`.

Comment: @blhsing Oh I see what you mean, I think OP requested for `unique` elements of the original list of tuples. Maybe we should wait for a further clarification on that.

Comment: I think the OP's intention is very clear from both the OP's verbiage of "keeping the tuple element that is not present in the *next* tuple" and the way the sample input is structured, with an item in each tuple always being the same as one of the items in the tuple immediately before it.

Comment: @blhsing I think the quoted expression is merely another way of saying, that he wishes that no duplicates exist in the final list. Maybe you are right, if he accepts your answer, I'll delete mine, how this sounds?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `functools.reduce` instead:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda a, b: [*a, *(i for i in b if i != a[-1])], lis)
```

This returns:

```
[31, 61, 79, 29, 103]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentatin of `accumulate()`,

> Argument: p [,func]
>
> Result:   p0, p0+p1, p0+p1+p2,...
>
> Example:  accumulate([1,2,3,4,5]) --> 1 3 6 10 15

So, for the code in the question `list(itertools.accumulate(lis, lambda a,b : a[0] if a[1] in b else a[1]))`

- The first argument to your function are the first two tuples i.e. `a = (31, 61) and b = (61, 79)` giving you the first result `31`
- Now the next argument to your function is `a = 31` and `b = (29, 79)`

And now you can see why you got the error.

To solve your problem you can try,

```py
[a[0] if a[1] in b else a[1] for a,b in zip(lis[:-1], lis[1:])] + list(lis[-1] if lis[-2][0] in lis[-1] else lis[-2])
```